# Geometric Intuition for Adding Projections

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, intuition, projective-geometry, orthogonality

Given a vector v in R^3, I was wondering why summing v's projections onto any two orthogonal vectors in a fixed plane yields the same result, from a geometric point of view.

Using the plane z = 0 as an example, I would hypothesize that

```
proj v onto [0, 1, 0] + proj v onto [1, 0, 0]
```

would yield a different vector (most likely in the opposite quadrant of the plane) than

```
proj v onto [0, -1, 0] + proj v onto [-1, 0, 0]
```

and that you would get a different vector still for

```
proj v onto [1, 2, 0] + proj v onto [2, -1, 0]
```

but when you crunch the numbers, these three calculations are the same.  Why is this the case?

Comment: Well. it's simply that you are computing the projection of $v$ onto that plane...

Comment: Right, and my question would be why the calculation for projection onto a plane makes sense geometrically, irrespective of the selected orthogonal vectors in the plane.

Comment: Let's introduce the symbol $u$ for the projection of $v$ onto the plane. You're picking an orthogonal basis for the plane and splitting $u$ into components with respect to that basis.